# How should I store permanent variables

Tags: android

I am making an app that my wife can use to check if a certain  IC friendly or not. The problem is that I need 5 columns if you will (foodName, safe, try, avoid,  foodCategory. Each may or may not have a description of the food name under **safe, try, avoid**. Should I use a `database` an `.xls` file or can I do it in `xml`?

Comment: I would use a database

Comment: You should use `SQLite`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array/Data Storage Options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950889/array-data-storage-options)

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html and make your choice.

Comment: I have rear developer.android.com however I am new at this I am sorry if this was not an appropriate question I have been trying to use a sqlite database but for som reason it can never open my table so I figured I was going about ti incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your requirement/ useage

use **sharedPreferences** or **sqlite database**

if you want to store data for long term use `sqlite`

and if you want to maintain sessions use `SharedPreferences`.

**SharedPreference**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Elena");
 editor.putInt("idName", 12);
 editor.commit();
```

Retrieve data from preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
  int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value. and it requires API 11
}
```

And for using Sqlite @Sri Hari have shown you an example..

Comment: sharedPreferences can not do task in his case. He is trying to store multiple rows (of 5 columns). So how can he do it?

Comment: @PankajKumar he know edited his question . I have answered it according to the previous question he has asked

Answer (score 0):

For storing data in android you can use:

- Shared Preferences - Store private primitive data in key-value pairs
- Internal Storage - Store private data on the device memory
- External Storage - Store public data on the shared external storage
- SQLite Databases - Store structured data in a private database
- Network Connection - Store data on the web with your own network
  server.

IMO for your purposes the most efficient option can be Shared Prefeerences or SQLite Database

More details for storing data you can find [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Please note that you can look also for some ORMs to make it easier with SQLite Database - GreenDAO, OrmLite,...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new SQLite database and store it. her you can store multiple tables safely.

```
public class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DICTIONARY_TABLE_NAME = "dictionary";
private static final String DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + DICTIONARY_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            KEY_WORD + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_DEFINITION + " TEXT);";

DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE);
}
}
```

Comment: This is the way I want to do it but how do I access the database that I created and where do I import it to in my application?

Comment: Read this article `http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/` using `cursor` we can access data from SQLite.